# Kids movie about a pre-teen boy wearing a Linkin Park hoodie, who ends up either time travelling or going through a magic portal

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was younger, around 2005, I watched a film that seemed late '90s/early '00s-y, about a kind of grumpy pre-teen boy wearing a Linkin Park hoodie throughout. I think he was American and moved somewhere in Europe (Scotland, Wales or Ireland from what I vaguely recall), and somehow got embroiled in either time travel or a magical portal. Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this film?

Comment: Hi thank you for responding! I was about 12 years old so this would’ve been around 2005

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @user149848 - I take it from your description that the boy was somehow transported to an unfamiliar time or place. Can you be a bit more specific about that? Did it look like medieval Europe? Were there any knights, castles, or wizards? Was there an antagonist? If so, can you describe them at all?

Comment: It wasn’t medieval, but it did seem in the past - it had a cottage core feel to it. I think at one point the characters in the film included an older man and young girl of the protagonist’s age - both of whom were native to this alternate setting. I think at one point they were chasing something, some kind of object that might’ve been taken by an animal. I think there was something about a significant door in the movie too.

Comment: I don’t think there was antagonist in the film. It definitely think the main conflict was as you said, trying to get the protagonist back to his time.